# How do I get pin from url?

Tags: twitter, twitter-oauth, scribe

After fetching request token i need to get a pin. And I got it. But its inside html page.
But all I need to get it from url.

I don't want to use my own site as callback, but I still want to get the pin.
With facebook api I can set https://www.facebook.com/connect/login_success.html as callback and it will return me https://www.facebook.com/connect/login_success.html?code=MYCODE and I can get the `code` parameter from url.

But twitter returns me https://dev.twitter.com/docs/auth/pin-based-authorization page without any code param.

So how do I get pin (code) from my app?

[image: twitter pin]

Answer (score 0):

you can try it https://github.com/raidenz/twitteroauth
with this app after user get the oauth_token user need to open link to get pin. and insert the pin back into the form to make this app work